Including a value in a range to be summed, only if a date is not today
I have a column of currency values that I sum. I only want each value in the column to be included in the sum if the date in that cells adjacent column is not equal to day's date (or in the future)

It sounds like you want to include all dates prior to the current date.Try this, assuming your currency values are in B:B and the date value is in A:A. You can wrap the criteria operator in quotes and connect it to the TODAY() function with an ampersand.
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,"<"&TODAY())

